# Why does GitHub invite me to enter two commit messages instead of just one?

Tags: git, github, commit, git-commit

This may be a basic question but I thought it would be worth asking.
On GitHub, when you add a file to a repository by clicking the plus
sign next to the repository's name, you get a text area where you can enter the contents of the file, followed by ***two*** commit messages:

[image]

However, when I use `git commit -m`, I can only specify ***one*** message. Hence my confusion...

Does the *optional extended description* on GitHub end up in the repository or not? After cloning the GitHub repository in question, how would I view such messages?

As far as I know, `git commit` only allows you to specify one message (using the `-m` flag), but maybe I'm missing something. Is there a way to specify a second
*extended message*, somehow?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### TL;DR

> [...] ***two*** commit messages [...]?

Two?! No; only one. The contents of those two text fields are combined to produce a *single* commit message. GitHub uses two text fields instead of one only to trick users into formatting their commit messages well.

### Details

The `git-commit` man page has a section entitled *Discussion*, which contains the following guidelines about the preferred format of commit messages:

> Though not required, it's a good idea to begin the commit message with
>   a single short (less than 50 character) line summarizing the change,
>   followed by a blank line and then a more thorough description. The
>   text up to the first blank line in a commit message is treated as the
>   commit title, and that title is used throughout Git.

When a user is about to create a commit directly on the GitHub site, she's invited to fill in two text fields:

1. The first text field corresponds to the *single short (less than 50 character) line summarizing the change*.
2. The second text field corresponds to the *more thorough description*.

By providing two text fields instead of one, GitHub helps the user follow the prescribed commit-message policy. Note, in particular, that you get a warning message if the number of characters typed in the first dialog box exceeds 50:

[image]

If you then run `git fetch` in your local repo and `git log`, you will see that the commit message is composed of the contents of both text fields:

```
$ git log
commit 0ef92f231cfbf2d4faf8f006e8ba19fc8169c099
Author: Jubobs xxxxxxxxxxxxxx
Date:   Wed Oct 1 10:39:15 2014 +0100

    write 'Hello, World!'

    - foo
    - bar
    - baz
```

Answer (score 1):

OK, I've cloned the GitHub repository with "git clone"
and by running a "git log" or "git commit --amend" I
can now see that the message consists of the first
50 character commit message line followed by a space
followed by the optional extended message.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

GitHub has done a magnificent job of "GUIfying" many of the operations of Git.

As you have stated, the 'git -m "message here" will provide what is known as a "short message" and it appears as the title when you use `git log`.

But, git supports much more text - which *is* stored as part of the commit.  That is what GitHub is providing for you in that second edit field; a chance to add a bit more detail to the commit message.
When you have the repository locally (as a result of `git clone`) you can see that 'extra' data if you modify the log output (for example `git log --pretty==fuller`).